# Find the primitive element of extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Find the primitive element of extension
$Q<Q(\sqrt{2}-i, \sqrt{3}+i) $

I am asking for help how to find a primitive element, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange ^.^

First, find that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, you can show this considering the image of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ by all the automorphism in the Galois group and showing that only the identity fix it.
Second, you can say that $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}-i,i-\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}-i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}-i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},i) $$
Third, you can show that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+i$ is the primitive element by showing, again, that the only automorphism that fix it is the identity. You can show this studying the Galois group and showing that is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ knowing that  containes three different normal subgroup of order 2 with trivial intersection corrisponding to the different subfields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ , $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$ and that it's order is 8.

Comment: Hello :),

Could you explain why we can say $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}-i,i-\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}-i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}-i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},i) $$ and why $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+i$ is primitive element (how to show that?). Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first equivalence is because you are taking a linear combination of the generators, so you can say that the firs field is contained in the second one because it containes the generator of the second one and viceversa. The second one is because $$ \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}-i) =  \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{2}-i) =  \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})( \sqrt{2}-i)=  \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}-i) $$

Comment: You show that is the primitive element showing that only the identity automorphism fixed it, so it must be in all the subfield  and it must be the primitive element. You can show that the identity is the only one fixing it showing that all the automorphism (that you know are composition of the three generators of the three copies of $C_2$ ) move it.

Comment: I can't show it, can you help me? I don't understand how to show it :(

Comment: Looking at the corrisponent subfield you can find the three generators of the three copies of $C_2$. For example, the copy of $C_2$ correspond to the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is the automorphism who send $i$ in $-i$, $\sqrt{2}$ in itself and $\sqrt{3}$ in itself. So all the automorphisms in the Galois group of the extension are the ones who send $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, $i$, in itselves or in their opposites. They are eight automorphism. All of them, beside the identity, move $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+i$.